# How to add horizontal scroll to inside row table of main table

Tags: html, html-table

How can i add horizontal scroll bar to child table inside the table. In the below code i am able to add the horizontal scroll bar to the main table, but the same attributes are not applying to the child table.

Is there any way to add the horizontal scroll bar to child table exist in particular row of main table ?

```html
<style> table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;} th, td {padding: 5px;}
</style>
<div style="overflow-x: auto;overflow-y:hidden;">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Records_fetched</th>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>NEw_records</th>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><p><b>Inside Table</b></p></th>
    <td>
        <div style="overflow-x: auto;overflow-y:hidden;">
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
            <th>Header4</th>
            <th>Header5</th>
            <th>Header6</th>
            <th>Header7</th>
            <th>Header8</th>
            <th>Header9</th>
            <th>Header10</th>
            <th>Header11</th>
            <th>Header12</th>
            <th>Header13</th>
            <th>Header14</th>
            <th>Header15</th>
            <th>Header16</th>
            <th>Header17</th>
            <th>Header18</th>
            <th>Header19</th>
            <th>Header20</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td>Data4</td>
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td>Data7</td>
            <td>Data8</td>
            <td>Data9</td>
            <td>Data10</td>
            <td>Data11</td>
            <td>Data12</td>
            <td>Data13</td>
            <td>Data14</td>
            <td>Data15</td>
            <td>Data16</td>
            <td>Data17</td>
            <td>Data18</td>
            <td>Data19</td>
            <td>Data20</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With define `max-width:300px;overflow:auto;` in the targeted element will make a horizontal scroll with a width limit is `300px`.

```css
#target {
  max-width:300px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

```html
<style> table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse;} th, td {padding: 5px;}
</style>
<div style="overflow-x: auto;overflow-y:hidden;">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Records_fetched</th>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>NEw_records</th>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th><p><b>Inside Table</b></p></th>
    <td id="target">
        <div style="overflow-x: auto;overflow-y:hidden;">
        <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Header1</th>
            <th>Header2</th>
            <th>Header3</th>
            <th>Header4</th>
            <th>Header5</th>
            <th>Header6</th>
            <th>Header7</th>
            <th>Header8</th>
            <th>Header9</th>
            <th>Header10</th>
            <th>Header11</th>
            <th>Header12</th>
            <th>Header13</th>
            <th>Header14</th>
            <th>Header15</th>
            <th>Header16</th>
            <th>Header17</th>
            <th>Header18</th>
            <th>Header19</th>
            <th>Header20</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Data1</td>
            <td>Data2</td>
            <td>Data3</td>
            <td>Data4</td>
            <td>Data5</td>
            <td>Data6</td>
            <td>Data7</td>
            <td>Data8</td>
            <td>Data9</td>
            <td>Data10</td>
            <td>Data11</td>
            <td>Data12</td>
            <td>Data13</td>
            <td>Data14</td>
            <td>Data15</td>
            <td>Data16</td>
            <td>Data17</td>
            <td>Data18</td>
            <td>Data19</td>
            <td>Data20</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Old_records</th>
    <td> 32 </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```